# bootstrap CSS: Change Navbar color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of the boostrap navbar like in this page
http://bootswatch.com/

where did they set that color? it seems to me they are actually using the standard CSS

Comment: They set the colors (foreground and background) in bootstrap.css line 4082. Y'know how I know? I right-clicked the navbar, and clicked Inspect element in the menu that came up. Any browser worth its salt should support standard web development features like that. Add `background-color` to the `.navbar-default` selector, and you're in business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect that page, you'll find that this color is in `.navbar-default` class. You can change to `background-color: #2c3e50` in bootstrap.css or make your css file like

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

and include this file after bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it through Dev Tools, it looks like they're setting the following rules in the bootstrap.css files:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Just make sure your navbar includes the `navbar-default` class.

Answer (score 0):

For the font color in the nav bar

can you check the below code

```
.navbar 
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#54b4eb, #2fa4e7 60%, #1d9ce5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#54b4eb, #2fa4e7 60%, #1d9ce5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#54b4eb, #2fa4e7 60%, #1d9ce5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff54b4eb',     
endColorstr='#ff1d9ce5', GradientType=0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #178acc;
    filter: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

If you see in navbar css in the background-image they are adding linear gradient  value

Regards
M

Answer (score 0):

*They* set it in a bootstrap.css file. It says on the site to install their product by replacing the existing bootstrap.css, so this makes sense. In general, I would suggest overwriting the bootstrap functionality in your own css file or using inline css unless you have a specific reason to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

As @aw04 pointed out, the styles are coming from their custom boostrap.css file, so if you wan't to take a theme in use take it from there properly.

However, if you just wan't the color, you would need to create a navbar which uses `.navbar-default` class as it has the required styles:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

For instance, here is **[js fiddle example of creating similar navbar](http://jsfiddle.net/wmA7d/)**